# Websocket внутри Foreground сервиса перестает быть активным когда выключается экран телефона

Tags: android

Декларация сервиса внутри `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
 <service 
     android:name=".service.MainService" 
     android:process=":mainService">
 </service>
```

Код сервиса

```
class MainService : Service() {
    private var locationUpdates: Disposable? = null
    private var lock: PowerManager.WakeLock? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startForeground()

        SocketService.instance.on("event") {
            // some 
        }
    }

    private fun startForeground() {
        val service = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        val channelId =
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                val id = "com.mypackage.foreground"
                val channel = NotificationChannel(id, "Foreground service", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH)
                channel.lightColor = Color.BLUE
                channel.lockscreenVisibility = Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE
                service.createNotificationChannel(channel)

                id
            } else {
                ""
            }

        val notificationBuilder = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId )
        val notification = notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true)
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.star_big_on)
            .setContentTitle("Foreground service")
            .setContentText("Don't kill it")
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
            .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_MESSAGE)
            .build()
        startForeground(42424242, notification)
    }

    override fun onBind(arg0: Intent): IBinder? {
        return null
    }
}
```

Пока экран активен, вебсокет работает исправно(получает и отправляет пакеты), но сразу же после отключения экрана он перестает работать, хотя уведомление о foreground процессе висит в системе.

Пробовал использовать `WakeLock`, не помогло:

```
class MainService : Service() {
    private var lock: PowerManager.WakeLock? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        startForeground()

        val pm = getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE) as PowerManager
        lock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, packageName.plus(":wake_lock"))
        lock?.acquire()

        ***
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()

        lock?.release()
    }

    ***
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте переопределить `onStartCommand` и вернуть из него `START_STICKY`. Это, вроде, должно восстанавливать сервис после прибития. Но это не будет работать на девайсах ряда производителей без доп. настроек системы. Однако, сделать бессмертный сервис в реальном мире невозможно в принципе. Разве что у вас все юзеры будут с рутованными девайсами строго определённого списка производителей и не будут обновлять ОС, которые введут новые ограничения. Подробности тут есть:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49637967/minimal-android-foreground-service-killed-on-high-end-phone